# Choosing a proper framework to the server side webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, frameworks

I'm writing a Android app and every time someone install it he must connect to a web server to get a updated data that it needs to work properly. The app does that only one time and after that is good to go on his own. Is a really small information, 1mb at top. But considering a lot of installation(hopefully) I was wondering what is the best framework to do that. What's your opinion?

Since this app is made in Java I was thinking about doing this "server side" part a RESTful service with Springboot but I don't know if it can handle a lot of simultaneous connections. And I don't think I'll need to implement "POST", "DELETE", "PUT". I just need(as far as I can see) to implement "GET". That's why I'm not sure if REST service is good idead. What do you people think?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my experience there are a lot of good frameworks that enable you to build backend applications and there is already a lot of comparisons you can find about it on web.

Since you are good at java I think springboot would be a good be really good option. Springboot is an excellent framework that is core to a lot of enterprise applications that use springboot and hence you don't have to worry about the performance. It would absolutely work well for you.

But if you are looking to quickly develop an application you could try with flask or django and both of them have also proved their mettle.

If you are good with javascript you could even try node. Except node maynot perform well for CPU intensive tasks but probably work very well if you are looking to fetch data with GET requests.

All of the above have a huge community support and hence you wouldn't have a problem learning it.

But if you are looking to implement something really really fast and not much complex checkout firebase. It might do the trick for you.